# How to write a Service Locator Pattern where the concrete classes implements the same interface/service?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service-locator

Consider the below

```
class ServiceA : IServiceA
    {
        public void SayHelloFromA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Service A");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }    
    class ServiceB : IServiceB{ } 
    class ServiceC : IServiceC{ }
    interface IServiceA 
    { 
        void SayHelloFromA(); 
    }
    interface IServiceB{ }
    interface IServiceC{ }
```

If I want to use a Service Locator Pattern, the example provided [here](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/09/25/service-locator-pattern-in-csharpa-simple-example/) works perfectly.

Now say another class implements the IServiceA interface as shown below.

```
class ServiceA1 : IServiceA
{
    public void SayHelloFromA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Service A1");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And correspondingly I need to add the service to the dictionary as under

```
internal ServiceLocator()    
        {        
            services = new Dictionary<object, object>();         

            this.services.Add(typeof(IServiceA), new ServiceA());
            this.services.Add(typeof(IServiceA), new ServiceA1());     
            this.services.Add(typeof(IServiceB), new ServiceB());        
            this.services.Add(typeof(IServiceC), new ServiceC());    
        }
```

And this is wrong as duplicate keys cannot be present in the dictionary.

So how can I solve this issue? How should the datastructure should be change so that the Service Locator can accomodate both.

N.B.~ I am trying to implement the Srvice Locator Pattern in my Factory Method

```
public class CustomerFactory : ICustomerBaseFactory

{

          public IBaseCustomer  GetCustomer(string  CustomerType)

          { 
                   switch(CustomerType)

                   { 
                             case "1": return  new Grade1Customer(); break;

                             case "2": return new Grade2Customer(); break;

                             default:return null; 
                   } 
          } 
}
```

where the Concrete Factories are deriving from **IBaseCustomer**

Thanks

Comment: How would you retrieve a specific implementation ? The whole point of the service locator is to give you an implementation of IServiceA without knowing which. In your example, how would you call the service locator to get a specific implementation ? (assuming you could have a keyed container with duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a Dictionary per abstract type keyed by the concrete type nested within a top-level Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<T, Dictionary<T, U>>
```

This way, you can query your top-level dictionary by type and then query the sub-dictionary for all services that implement that type.

e.g.

```
var services = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Object>>();
```

Now you can ask the services dictionary for a type:

```
services.TryGetValue(typeof(IServiceA), componentDictionary);
```

If this returns true then you know that componentDictionary will contain the components that implement that service:

```
foreach (c in componentDictionary.Values) {... }
```

With smart use of abstract base types and generics you could create a more strongly typed solution than this. However, this should work reasonably well, albeit with casting.

Comment: I've updated the answer to demonstrate the concept a little further. Basically, your service locator needs an Identity Map to hold/resolve components to services.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, there's a **MultiMap** class that supports multiple values per key. I'm sure you can find a similar data structure for C# as well.

Comment: It's not part of JDK, however. If you have to use pure java use Map with `List` as values. More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html